# How to disable button in Ant Design Input.Search component

Tags: reactjs, antd

In my application for a search bar I use Input.Search Ant Design component.
For example like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'antd';

const SearchBar = ( { loading, searchHandler } ) => (
  <Input.Search placeholder="Enter name to search here"
                disabled={loading}
                onSearch={searchHandler}
                enterButton='Search' />          
);

export default SearchBar;
```

This way when `loading` property is `true` input field is disabled, but the button is still clickable. 
I want to disable *both* parts of control, the field and the button, while `loading` prop is `true`, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can handle it in your `searchHandler`:

```
searchHandler = e => {
  if(this.state.loading) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }else {
    // Do stuff..
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like you can [supply your own custom enterButton](https://ant.design/components/input/#Input.Search). So I would create a new component for the enter button and pass it `loading` as a prop:

```
const EnterButton = ({ loading, onClick }) => (
    <button className={loading ? 'disabled' : ''} onClick={onClick} disabled={loading}>Search</button>
);

export default EnterButton;

...

import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'antd';
import EnterButton from './EnterButton';

const SearchBar = ( { loading, searchHandler } ) => (
    <Input.Search placeholder="Enter name to search here"
                  disabled={loading}
                  onSearch={searchHandler}
                  enterButton={<EnterButton loading={loading} onClick={searchHandler} />} />
);

export default SearchBar;
```

You can use the `loading` prop to disable the button and add a `.disabled` class to it.

```
.disabled { opacity: 0.5; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is really helpful for me, but I'm figured out that have stated my question in a wrong way. I'm more interested in making the button visually disabled.

Comment: @timur Ah okay, updated my answer to show how that can be done.